# Creating multiple folders within multiple folders.

Tags: powershell, command-line

Im looking to create multiple folders within multiple folders, but only in those foldersthat end with , Location.

**Folders to create**

```
06.8 Principal Designer (PD)
06.9 Structural Engineering Registry (SER)
```

**Folders to create in**

```
4000 Project Title, Location
4001 Project Title, Location
4002 Project Title, Location
...
4999 Project Title, Location
```

EXAMPLE:
XXXX Project Title, Location\06. Reports\06.8 Principal Designer (PD)

**My current non working code**

```
for /d  %a in ('dir c:\temp\temp\*location ') do md 'C:\temp\temp\%a\06. Reports\06.8 Principal Designer (PD)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks like `cmd` not PowerShell. I will answer assuming that you intend to use the regular Command Prompt.

To iterate over directories use `for /d`:

```
for /d %a in (C:\Temp\Temp\*location) do md "%a\06.8 Principal Designer (PD)"
```

Single quotes are not special to `cmd.exe`; use double quotes around file names containing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

in PowerShell

```
$dirtocreate =('06.8 Principal Designer (PD)', '06.9 Structural Engineering Registry (SER)')
Get-ChildItem "c:\temp\temp\*Location" -Directory | %{$dir=$_.FullName;$dirtocreate | %{New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "$dir\$_" } }
```